# One Large Bitmap vs. Many Small Bitmaps

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I'm making a card game for android and need to load in bitmaps for the entire deck of cards. Would it be more memory efficient to create a separate image for each card and load them in one by one, or to create one large image with all 52 cards and then load in the single, large image?

Comment: Large image is much faster and better on memory..  Think of it like a sprite-map.

Comment: @Jasz There's no evidence that `Large image is much faster and better on memory`. I'd rather say that **a large image is more inclined to cause an OOM error**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't say it's necessarily faster or better to load in the images as a large sprite image. You'd then have to cut the bitmap up for each card and load the individual bitmaps onto the cards anyway if you're using android widgets. If you're rendering it all on canvas then it may be better to load a large bitmap image and cut it up as you need.

The only issue I'd be wary of, especially on Android, is out of memory exceptions. I have a few production apps and have seen in the real world the number of phones that crash because they run out of space to store bitmaps. It may well work nicely on your development phone but there are plenty of devices out there with much smaller screens, resolutions and therefore RAM. It may be in your interest in that case to load bitmaps individually as you can ensure only show ones currently visible, hence save on memory.

52 cards are 52 different images - I don't know many games where you would see all of them at the same time.

**edit**

What would really save memory would be if you just stored the suit symbols, numbers and special card icons (jack, queen, king, ace) and then arranged them on a card that you generate. Then you wouldn't have all the blank space around parts of the card taking up precious memory and you could reuse the special card icons for different suits by tinting the icons different colours.

Comment: I was planning on loading the card images at the beginning, but are you saying to load each one as it becomes visible? If so, wouldn't that slow the app down considerably? And yes, I am rendering it all on a canvas.

Comment: @Thomas No, it won't slow down. And it would save memory, to load only the needed cards.